# How to Navigate to CameraCaptureTask from LensPicker

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have created a small sample Lens application, and I would like to be able to directly navigate to the CameraCaptureTask when the Lens icon is clicked in the default camera application. In my application I am already calling the CameraCaptureTask within a button click event during normal app operations. How might I set this up to work as well from the LensPicker option?

I have been referencing 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662936(v=vs.105).aspx

LensExampleUriMapper.cs

```
private string tempUri;

public override Uri MapUri(Uri uri)
{
    tempUri = uri.ToString();

    // Look for a URI from the lens picker.
    if (tempUri.Contains("ViewfinderLaunch"))
    {
        // Launch as a lens, launch viewfinder screen.
        return new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
    }

    // Otherwise perform normal launch.
    return uri;
}
```

I was thinking of passing a QueryString value in `return new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative);` so that in my MainPage `OnNavigatedTo` event I could check that QueryString value and call the CameraCaptureTask, and then just route the result to the already existing event handler I have created (which displays the resulting image in MainPage). For some reason I am getting a debugging error when trying to create the QueryString to pass, and I am unsure of why?

EDIT** No longer getting error, but an infinite loop occurs when calling CameraCaptureTask. Why?

LensExampleUriMapper.cs

```
private string tempUri;

public override Uri MapUri(Uri uri)
{
    tempUri = uri.ToString();

    // Look for a URI from the lens picker.
    if (tempUri.Contains("ViewfinderLaunch"))
    {
        // Launch as a lens, launch viewfinder screen.
        return new Uri("/MainPage.xaml?fromLensPicker=" + "fromLensPicker", UriKind.Relative);
    }

    // Otherwise perform normal launch.
    return uri;
}
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    string fromLensPicker = null;
    if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("fromLensPicker", out fromLensPicker))
    {
        if (fromLensPicker == "fromLensPicker")
        {
            newButton_Click(null, null);  //click event that calls CameraCaptureTask
            fromLensPicker = null; //Temporarily nullifies value until MainPage is OnNavigatedTo after CameraCaptureTask completes
        }
    }
}
```

I believe that when `CameraCaptureTask` is called, the application is tombstoned and then resumed on MainPage, in which the `QueryString` value `fromLensPicker == "fromLensPicker"` and the entire cycle starts over again, repetitively. How might I solve this?

Comment: Can you include the code where the QueryString error occurs?

Comment: Actually, I wasn't checking the value of `tempUri` properly, it contained more in the string than I was checking before deciding whether to just navigate to MainPage or insert a querystring as well.

Comment: Actually I have noticed that I am getting an infinite loop called to my button click event that calls the CameraCaptureTask, and thus can never get out of the task. I edited my original post to reflect this. It has to deal with tombstoning I believe. How might I clear the querystring values once a page has been navigated to and retrieved them so they no longer exist when arriving back at that same page from CameraCaptureTask?

Answer (score 0):

Use NavigationMode property in MainPage. I think you can't clear QueryString. But you can check how navigation to your page occured to know if its returning from CameraCaptureTask

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.New)
    // continue further
}
```

or

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.Back)
    return;

    // else continue further
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making `fromLensPicker = null` in `MainPage.xaml.cs`, I now have `NavigationContext.QueryString.Remove("fromLensPicker")` as referenced from [WP7 Navigation with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12159071/wp7-navigation-with-parameters)

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    string fromLensPicker = null;
    if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("fromLensPicker", out fromLensPicker))
    {
        if (fromLensPicker == "fromLensPicker")
        {
            NavigationContext.QueryString.Remove("fromLensPicker");                           
            //Perform Action           
        }
    }
}
```